If the base change is a fiber product, is the original variety a fiber product too?
Assume we have an extension of algebraically closed fields $L/K$ and varieties $V_1$ and $V_2$ over $K$. Let $W_1\subseteq (V_1)_L$ and $W_2\subseteq (V_2)_L$ subvarieties, so $W_1\times_L W_2\subseteq (V_1)_L\times_L(V_2)_L$. If we know $W_1\times_L W_2=W'_L$ for a subvariety $W'$ of $V_1\times_K V_2$, does that imply $W'=W'_1\times_K W'_2$ for subvarieties $W'_i\subseteq V_i$?
I believe this is not the case, but find it hard to come up with a counterexample in which $W'$ if contained in the fiber product.
We are assuming varieties to be projective and irreducible.

Are your varieties projective?

@Sasha Yes they are. I should have mentioned this. They are also irreducible.

Let $H_i$ be the restrictions to $W'$ of the pullbacks of very ample divisors from $V_i$. Let $W'_i$ be the image of $W'$ under the morphism defined by $H_i$. Consider the induced morphism
$$
f : W' \to W'_1 \times W'_2.
$$
Since the morphisms defined by divisors commute with filed extensions, it follows that $f_L$ is an isomorphism. But then $f$ is also an isomorphism.
